# PHP sessions permission issue between directories, global variables acting local to their own directory

Tags: php, linux, session, directory, global

I have a PHP sessions permission problem. I am using a Linux server running an up-to-date version of PHP. The issue is I set session variables in `/var/www/session/here.php` and then the session variables load fine in that PHP files and other PHP files the same directory. I am using `session_start();` at the beginning of every PHP page.

I am using this to set the sessions:

```
$_SESSION['example1'] = 983982;
```

And this to view them:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

When I access `/var/www/training/unit2/lesson4/here.php` (a different directory) it does not recognize the variables saved in the global session array, in fact when I make new session variables in that different directory they work fine but the other session variables from before do not show up.  When I move the file to the same directory as the other PHP files, the session variables work fine.

I understand this must be some type of  PHP global sessions permissions issue. Any ideas what file I have to modify to correct this? When I make new session variables they should be available on every PHP page in any directory. The session vars are getting stored some place with a relative path that is getting broken when they are called from PHP pages in different directories.

Sessions are stored in session.save_path in php.ini. The default location of session vars is `/var/lib/php5` which is in a different directory than either of the PHP files I am testing so they should both be able to access it?

Comment: Might even be a folder permissions issue.

Comment: What URL do you type in your browser for both pages ? Are they using the same **base domain name** (e.g. `localhost/session/here.php` and `localhost/training/unit2/lesson4.php`) ? By base domain name, I mean `localhost` in my previous examples. Session will vary if it isn't the same domain name.

Comment: Yes they are both using the same domain name. www.X.com/session/test.php and www.X.com/training/unit2/lesson4/here.php

A folder permissions? so  you mean I should use chmod to change the folder settings? what permissions should each folder use? under the Permissions column in my FTP both have -rw-r--r--

Comment: Are you checking if the session has already been started? e.g.
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

Comment: My understanding of the session_start(); function is that it needs to be called first on any page that reads or writes to global session variables.  The sessions variables work fine when between php files in the same directory.  But once I access a page one directory back and 3 forward it the php files do not even see any of the session variables already created.  Session variables are supposed to be global and therefore should be view-able on any page hosted on the sever.

Comment: Is it possible that the settings of the folder permissions (chmod) for the   /var/lib/php/session directory could be causing this?